# Material that emits light, but appears diffuse?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

How can I have an object that emits light (using an emission shader) onto other objects, but when rendered appears to be diffuse (or any other shader for that matter)?

In essence, I want one object to emit light that shows on other objects, but that only itself receives light from other objects (not itself). Is this possible?

I tried doing this using Max/Add Shader nodes, but this just mixed in the "pure white" emission shader look with the diffuse shader I was using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the *Is Camera Ray* output of the [Light Path node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html?#light-path-node) to mix the shaders.

[image: example node setup]

Comment: How did you get the Light Path node to only show the Is Camera Ray output?

Comment: @gandalf3, Toggle Hidden Node Sockets: _Ctrl+H_.

Comment: Ah, thanks.. learn something new every day ;)