# Objects with Emission shader emit light but appear gray, not bright

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

This happens even if I create a new mesh with a new material. All item with emission appear like that large plane above the building. Emission power is 60.
If I create e new scene, however, everything works fine.

Blender version: 2.76 - Cycles Render
[image: Large emitting plane appears gray]

Comment: What is material setup for emission plane ? Isn't it set up to [emit light but seem like diffuse](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/material-that-emits-light-but-appears-diffuse) ?

Comment: Excuse me for the delay. Apparently the problem was fixed setting the "clamp" value do zero and using "indirect clamp" instead (under Render > Sampling)

Comment: It may be necessary to set *Clamp Indirect* to higher values too, see [related question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47358/why-does-this-mirror-made-using-a-glossy-material-not-fully-reflect-all-the-in). If this worked for you consider writing an answer with some details on how you solved that.